# Auto-scrolling a large image

Tags: android, image, scroll

I basically need to auto scroll vertically on a long image (something like 2000-3000 pixels long) on Android.

- I tried a translateAnimation with an image from the Assets folder, but unfortunately it only showed the first part of the image, the animation only showed white during the movement.
- I also tried a ScrollView with an ImageView, and I used the ScrollTo method in a loop, but it didn't show the animation itself, just the result:

  ```
  public void scroll(View view)
  {
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++)
      {
          scrollView.scrollTo(0, i);
          try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
  }
  ```

Maybe I did something wrong, anyone knows another solution I might use ?